# how to prove: if $\mathscr{F}_i, i\in I$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$ is

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I ran into this conclusion on $\sigma$-algebra:

If $\mathscr{F}_i, i\in I$ are $\sigma$-algebras, then $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

Note here  $I$ is an arbitrary index set (i.e., possibly uncountable).

How to prove that?

Update: thanks for Michael Albanese's hint, i think it can be proved as below:

$\sigma$-algebra is defined as below (quoted from Bernt Oksendal's "Stochasticc Differential Equations" ch 2, pg 7)

Definition 2.1.1 If $\Omega$ is a given set, then a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{F}$ on $\Omega$ is a family $\mathscr{F}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ with the following proerties

1. $\varnothing  \in \mathscr{F}$
2. $F \in \mathscr{F} \Rightarrow F^C \in \mathscr{F}$, where $F^C = \Omega \backslash F$ is the complement of F in $\Omega$
3. $A_1, A_2, \cdots \in \mathscr{F} \Rightarrow A:=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \mathscr{F}$

Note the property 3 is only about countable union, while the one in the question is using an index set, which can be uncountable.

Define $\mathscr{F} := \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$, to prove $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is to prove it fulfills the 3 conditions.

For Condition 1, there's no problem:

$\forall \mathscr{F}_i, \varnothing \in \mathscr{F}_i$, so $\varnothing \in  \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i = \mathscr{F}$

For condition 2, it's also OK:

$\forall F\in\mathscr{F}$, $F\in \mathscr{F} = \bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$.

So $\forall i \in I$, $F \in \mathscr{F}_i$.

Since $\mathscr{F}_i$ is $\sigma$-algebra, $F^C \in \mathscr{F}_i$.

So $F^C \in \mathscr{F}$.

Condition 3 is similiar:

$\forall A_1, A_2, \cdots (countable) \in \mathscr{F} \Rightarrow \forall i \in I, A_1, A_2, \cdots \in \mathscr{F}_i$.

So $\forall i \in I$, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \mathscr{F}_i$.

so $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \mathscr{F}$.

So $\mathscr{F}$ is $\sigma$-algebra.

QED.

Retrospecting, I think i made the mistake that, although $\mathbb{F}$ is defined as an uncountable joint of sets, the $\sigma$-algebra's conditions are only defined based on the (countable) operations of sets in the set family.

Comment: A collection of subsets of a set $X$ forms a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ if it satisfies three conditions. Have you checked these three conditions? Is there one you are stuck on?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese pls see my update

Comment: Which of these conditions are you struggling to verify?

Comment: conditions 1, 2, and 3 are definition, there's no need to verify. But i have problem to prove that $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$ is $\sigma$-algebra. The condition 3 couldn't help here as it's about countable union, while the questions is about uncountable index set.

Comment: There's no need to verify them for each of the $\mathscr{F}_i$ as you are told they are $\sigma$-algebras, but you want to show $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}\mathscr{F}_i$ is a $\sigma$-algebra so you have to verify the three conditions for this collection.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese thanks Michael, i misunderstood your hint. I think i came up the proof, as updated in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that you have included in your most recent edit is correct, though one of the $\mathscr{F}_i$'s becomes an $F_i$.